# iife javascript variable lifetime

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

how come a variables value within the immediate scope of an iife, survives in a similar way to a global variable in terms of holding it's value. This is really confusing me.

```
(function(){
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var count = 0;
    display.innerHTML = 0;

    button.onclick = function(){
        count ++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
    }
})();
```

Comment: It survives like a variable in any other closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It survives because there's still a reference to it in one of your HTMLElements.

When you attach that lambda to the `button.onclick` property, there is a reference to `count` inside the lambda.

So long as that HTMLElement survives, or that `onclick` property remains assigned to that lambda, then `count` will survive too.

Answer (score 1):

That's called a "closure".

Your function refers to `display` and `count` in its body, so it will "capture" those variables and "keep them alive" as long as it itself is alive (which it will here because you attached it to the DOM as an event handler).